# Push PHP fetch array datas to ajax request and return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got a while loop table which displays info from my database. And what I'd like to achieve is to put a notification on each row like how many new comments that specific ticket it has.

Here's my **while loop** code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
    $cTicketNo=$row["cTicketNo"];
    $vCategory=$row["vCategory"];
    $cUsername=$row["cUsername"];
    $cPCName=$row["cPCName"];
    $dDateTimeCalled=$row["dDateTimeCalled"];
    $vDepartment=$row["vDepartment"];
    $cRStatus=$row["cRStatus"];
    $nFollowup=$row["nFollowUp"];
    $cUStatus=$row['cUStatus'];
    $trID='p'.$i;
    echo '<form action="Ticket-Assign.php" method="GET">';
    echo "<tr id='$trID' onclick=\"highlightClicked('$trID','$maxi')\">";   
    echo "<td class='center'>$nFollowup</td>";          
    echo "<td id='ticket' class='center'>$cTicketNo</td>";
    echo "<td class='center'>$vCategory</td>";
    echo "<td class='center'>$cUsername</td>";
    echo "<td class='center'>$cPCName</td>";
    echo "<td class='center'>$dDateTimeCalled</td>";
    echo "<td class='center'>[ <a id='comment' href='s_ViewAllActions.php?cTicketNo=$cTicketNo' onclick=\"highlightClicked('$trID','$maxi')\">Comment</a> ]</a><div id='noti_Counter'></div></td>";
}
```

If you look at the div with id noti_Counter, that's where I would like the notifications counter to appear.

Here's my **AJAX** code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_unseen_notification();
    function load_unseen_notification()
    {
        var ticketno= $("#ticket").text();
        $.ajax({
            url:"check.php",
            method:"GET",
            data:{ticketno:ticketno},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.unseen_notification > 0)
                {
                    $('#noti_Counter')
                    .css({ opacity: 0 })
                    .animate({  opacity: 1 }, 500);
                }
            }
         });
    }

      setInterval(function(){
      load_unseen_notification();
      }, 5000);

});
```

Here's the **check.php**, I just minized it:

```
$cTicketNo = santize($_GET["ticketno"]);
$query_1 = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_status=0 AND cTicketNo='". $cTicketNo ."'";
$result_1 = mysql_query($query_1) or die (mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result_1);
$data = ['unseen_notification' => $count];
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Can anyone please help, I am new to AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add to your jquery statement in your ajax() complete function to fill the result data into your HTML element:

```
 $('#noti_Counter').html(data.unseen_notification).css({ opacity: 0 }).animate({  opacity: 1 }, 500);
```

This will set the inner HTML of #noti_counter to the value of data.unseen_notification before animating it.

**Edit:** I just noticed "data:{ticketno:ticketno}" in your ajax() call, you may need to add quotations to the first one to ensure it is treated as the literal text rather than the variable value.

I also noticed you did not close the tr tag in the HTML which will be a problem for the solution described below.

Your biggest issue is with way you are calling the ajax function. This is a bit of a strange use as you are already using php to create the page content and you could just skip the ajax and include the code from check.php in your page body. because you have multiple instances of #ticket you will need to use jquery to iterate through the set and call the ajax handler for each.

You will want to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    JQuery.fn.load_unseen_notification = function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"check.php",
            method:"GET",
            data:{'ticketno':$this.text()},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(xhr)
            { 
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if(data.unseen_notification > 0)
                {
                    $(this).parents("tr").find('#noti_Counter').html(data.unseen_notification).css({ opacity: 0 }).animate({  opacity: 1 }, 500);
                }
            }
         });
    }

   $("#ticket").each(function(){
     $(this).load_unseen_notification();
   });
});
```

This is pretty messy though, it will iterate through the #ticket objects to get the value to send for each instance and semi abuses jquery to find the correct #noti_counter object to fill. It would be better to call all your PHP together either in the page body or in the ajax call and then use the result to generate your HTML.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But it's still not returning anything. When I look at the console ~ check.php?ticketno=S043397 500 (Internal Server Error) ~ that's the error, I think it's passing only one value. Where in I got like 2 rows on the page.

Comment: I know I see some more issues, I'm editing my answer

Comment: It's expected that it will only pass one value and get called twice. The jquery plugin I wrote will find all the #ticket objects and run the Ajax function to call check.php for each one. The 500 error in the console means there was a PHP error in check.php look in your web server logs to find out what went wrong.